# Cmus not responding to keyboard on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, cmus

cmus is not responding to keyboard input on Ubuntu 16.04.3. Neither restarting cmus nor restarting the machine have helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the contents of `~/.config/cmus` fixed the issue.